# Need help checking for multiple underscores in a collection of files - see code below

Tags: python, sorting, if-statement

I am working on a project where I need to sort .jpg files and folders that contain .jpg files. I have other scripts that are functional which I intend to incorporate into this python script later. First though, I've implemented in the first script below to count the number of underscores in a file and take action based on the result and this works successfully. I need help on creating logic that will go through .jpg image files and if the files have more than one underscore the program will move the files into an error folder. Also any feedback on how to optimize this script would be greatly appreciated!

```
from pathlib import Path
import shutil, os, time, glob

timestr = time.strftime("%Y%m%d-%H%M%S")

folder = 'D:\\test\\testing'
working_folder = 'DitaTest1'
full_path = Path(os.path.join(folder, working_folder))
test_path = folder + '\\' + working_folder

for file_path in full_path.iterdir():
    file_name = file_path.name
    result = file_name.count('_')

    if file_path.is_file():
        os.chdir(test_path)
        for file in glob.glob("*.jpg"):
            dst=test_path+"\\"+file.replace(" ","_").replace(".jpg","") # .replace("Angle","").replace("Front","").replace("Side","")
            os.mkdir(dst)
            # print(dst)
            shutil.move(file,dst)
    elif result != 1:
        if not file_path.is_file():
            shutil.move(os.path.join(folder, working_folder, file_name), os.path.join(folder, working_folder + ' - dir-ERRORS_' + timestr, file_name))
        else:
            print('Ignored operation')
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to explain more so that we can understand it better but from what I have read,

1. Your if logic seems to be wrong, if you want to check the number of underscores you shouldn't put that logic in `elif`. You should try sth like this instead.

```py
for file_path in full_path.iterdir():
    file_name = file_path.name
    result = file_name.count('_')
    
    if os.path.isdir(file_path):
        pass
    else:
        if result == 1:
            os.chdir(test_path)
            for file in glob.glob("*.jpg"):
                dst=test_path+"\\"+file.replace(" ","_").replace(".jpg","") # .replace("Angle","").replace("Front","").replace("Side","")
                os.mkdir(dst)
                # print(dst)
                shutil.move(file,dst)
        else:
            shutil.move(os.path.join(folder, working_folder, file_name), os.path.join(folder, working_folder + ' - dir-ERRORS_' + timestr, file_name))
```

What this code does is, iterate over the folder and if it finds a folder it will just pass and when it finds a file it will check if `result == 1`. If it is it will move it to your desired folder, otherwise it will move it to the error folder. If I made a mistake let me know.